# accessing bootstrap tabs in .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create an inbox which shows my users their sent message through jQuery's .load() when they click on the message title.

The problem that I am having is that the loaded message contains bootstrap tabs, which I can't do not work.  I know the reason that they don't work is because they were added after the  was loaded and they need to "bubble up".   I just can't seem to make them "bubble up".

main page contains:

```
<div id="message-view" class="block-section display-none">
    </div>
```

.load() page, which is added to the  above:

```
<div id="messageDetailView">
         <!-- Message Body -->
            <hr>
               {{$message->body}}
            <hr>

         <!-- Tabs -->
            <div class="block-section">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs testTabs" data-toggle="tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#sent">Sent</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#open">Opened</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#bounced"><i class="gi gi-settings">Bounced</i></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
          <!-- Tabs Content -->
             <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="sent">Sent</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="open">Open</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="bounced">Bounced</div>
              </div>
        <!-- END Tabs Content -->
        <!-- END Tabs -->
    </div>
```

Script:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.sentMessage', displayMessage);
    function displayMessage(){
        var messageId = $(this).attr("id");
        var inboxView = $('#message-view');

        inboxView
            .load( baseURL+'/contractors/messageDetails/'+messageId)
            .removeClass('display-none')
            .addClass('animation-fadeInQuick2');

        $('#messageDetailView').appendTo('#message-view');
    };
```

I thought .append() would work, but it doesn't.

```
$('#messageDetailView').appendTo('#message-view');
```

I have also tried appending to the 'body' and putting the .appendTo inside of a separate function with its own event handler.   How do I go about making the tabs accessible to the script?

Answer (score 0):

stopPropagation() is what I was after.

```
$('body').on('click', '.nav-tabs a', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).tab('show');
    });
```

Chalk this up to lack of sleep, I guess.